# How to stop the polling of @InboundChannelAdapter when kafka went down to prevent data loss?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

i am using spring cloud data flow.

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = TbeSource.PR1, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "2"))
public Supplier<Product> getProductSource(ProductBuilder dataAccess) {

    return ()->dataAccess.getNext();
        
    };
```

if the kafka was went down suddenly then how can we stop this polling behaviour to prevent the data loss?

while i am testing even if kafka went down data is continously readed from database and continously it is trying to send the record to kafka?

Expected performance is to stop the data polling once the kafka went down..

Is there any possible ways to perform that?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Poller` of the `@InboundChannelAdapter` can be configured with an `errorChannel`:

```
/**
 * @return The the bean name of default error channel
 * for the underlying {@code MessagePublishingErrorHandler}.
 * @since 4.3.3
 */
String errorChannel() default "";
```

So, whenever exception happens downstream the flow on that `TbeSource.PR1` channel, it is going to be delivered to the provided error channel for some error flow on it.

Over there you could follow the logic to stop the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` created for that `@InboundChannelAdapter` and `Supplier` combination. In this case the bean id is like this: `[CONFIGURATION_CLASS_BEAN_NAME.getProductSource.inboundChannelAdapter]`. See here for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans. As it states you also can just use an `@EndpointId` instead to simplify your life with dependency injection routine.

Make sure you rethrow an exception to let DB transaction to roll back to avoid data loss!